# How to paginate at field level in cypher query?

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

Actually, I have a node say **NodeA** which contains following fields:

- id
- name
- friends

**friends** field is nothing but `Set<String> friends` in **NodeA** class.
If size of friends is huge say 3000 or 5000 or more, How can I paginate through the fields of NodeA ?
For instance: I am firing below query:
`start event=node(12) return event.friends;` which returns me list of friends as :
`["abc","devid","rao","amn","xyz","pqr"]`.
Is there any way, through which I can select only first 3 friends and so on ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, there is no generic way to do that, I'm afraid. However, such a function is in the works, according to the devs: http://grokbase.com/t/gg/neo4j/137hhxyer6/cypher-getting-the-first-n-elements-of-a-collection

For now you only could model your friends as nodes of their own and connect them to NodeA via relationships, e.g. of type `HAS_FRIEND`. Then, you could do some kind of pageing via `skip` and `limit`.